# Espresso: Test TextInputLayout PasswordVisibilityToggle button

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-espresso

Good day, am getting to grips with espresso and am trying to check if the PasswordVisibilityToggleEnabled button of a TextInputLayout is visible or not. I know this button is a CheckableImageButton with the id (`R.id.text_input_password_toggle)` but not sure how to get it in Espresso.

I tried doing this:

```
onView(withId(R.id.passwordTextInputLayout)).check(hasDescendant(withId(R.id.text_input_password_toggle))).check(matches(not(isDisplayed())));
```

But this is not working. I guessed i might have to use a custom Matcher based on a few questions on StackOverflow but am not sure if am doing that correctly.

```
public static Matcher<View> getPasswordToggleView(final Matcher<View> parentMatcher, int id) {
    return new TypeSafeMatcher<View>() {
        @Override
        protected boolean matchesSafely(View view) {
            if(!(view.getParent() instanceof ViewGroup)) {
                return parentMatcher.matches(view.getParent());
            }

            ViewGroup group = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
            return  parentMatcher.matches(view.getParent()) && view.getId() == id;
        }

        @Override
        public void describeTo(Description description) {
            description.appendText("get View with matching id");
        }
    };
}
```

and try to use it like this but still not working:

```
 onView(getPasswordToggleView(withId(R.id.passwordTextInputLayout), R.id.text_input_password_toggle)).check(matches(not(isDisplayed())));
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code:

```
onView(withId(R.id.passwordTextInputLayout))
    .check(hasDescendant(withId(R.id.text_input_password_toggle))) // assume you forgot matches(...)
    .check(matches(not(isDisplayed())));
```

The last check `not(isDisplayed))` is performed on TextInputLayout, and not its `CheckableImageButton` as you expected. To fix this error, simply rearrange your code to:

```
onView(withId(R.id.passwordTextInputLayout))
    .check(matches(allOf(hasDescendant(withId(R.id.text_input_password_toggle)), not(isDisplayed()))))
```

So that it can perform display check on the button.

Alternatively if you want to create a custom matcher for `TextInputLayout`, you can try:

```
public static Matcher<View> isPasswordVisibilityToggleEnabled() {
    return new BoundedMatcher<View, TextInputLayout>(TextInputLayout.class) {

        @Override public void describeTo(Description description) {
            description.appendText("is password visibility toggle enabled");
        }

        @Override protected boolean matchesSafely(TextInputLayout view) {
            return view.isPasswordVisibilityToggleEnabled();
        }
    };
}
```

Then you can change your test code to:

```
onView(withId(R.id.passwordTextInputLayout))
    .check(matches(not(isPasswordVisibilityToggleEnabled())))
```

I think `view.isPasswordVisibilityToggleEnabled()` is sufficient enough for a simple test in this case, but feel free to tweak the matcher as you like.

Comment: It doesn't work. I got a : junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: '(has descendant: with id: 2131296788 and not is displayed on the screen to the user)' doesn't match the selected view.
Expected: (has descendant: with id: com.MyPackageName:id/text_input_password_toggle and not is displayed on the screen to the user) it seems it can't find the ID correctly

Comment: When i use the custom Matcher like in your example, it works but if i try to use the Has descendants, i get the error like in my previous comments

Comment: I could be wrong but maybe you created the same id name under your app resource. If it's true then just remove it. Or try replace `withId(R.id.text_input_password_toggle)` with `ViewMatchers.isAssignableFrom(CheckableImageButton.class)`. And make sure  it's `not(isDisplayed())` if you expect the toggle to be disabled.

Comment: Thanks. For some reason, it still not working but i have gone with your other proposal about using the custom matcher which works. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

As long as you're (apparently) already fine using id of toggle button, you can do this `onView(withId(R.id.text_input_password_toggle)).check(doesNotExist())` to check toggle button is not displayed. This validation will succeed if `passwordToggleEnabled` is false.

`doesNotExist` is part of `android.support.test.espresso.assertion`